# How to reference multiple columns' values in a subquery?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-server-2012

I've tried to run the following instructions in SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT ID, Title
from Movies
where categoryID = 1 and (MovieID,1) in 
        (select MovieID, count(ID)
            from Copies
            group by (MovieID))
```

But the following error message is thrown:

*
Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.*

I know that this query runs perfectly in PostgreSQL. What should I change in order to run properly in SQL Server 2012?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this using standard join syntax instead:

```
SELECT m.ID, m.Title
FROM Movies m
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT c.MovieID FROM Copies c GROUP BY c.MovieID HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
    ) cc ON m.MovieID = cc.MovieID
WHERE m.categoryID = 1
```

Comment: @Mudkip: And that's how you should do it in Postgres as well - minus arbitrary capitalization of identifiers. Without enclosing double quotes those are folded to lower case anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.ID, m.Title
from Movies m
where m.categoryID = 1 
and 1 = (select count(*)
         from copies c
         where c.MovieID = m.MovieID);
```